# FOSUserBundle OracleXE 11g (ORA-00903: invalid table name)

Tags: oracle11g, fosuserbundle, symfony

I started a project with oracle 11g. The connection works well. I installed FOSUserBundle and updated the datatbase, everything is ok. The able user is created but when I tried to create user.

```
C:>php bin/console fos:user:create admin
```

> Please choose an email:helmis@gmail.de Please choose a password:
>   [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException] An exception occurred while
>   executing 'INSERT INTO user (username, username
>   _canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, lo cked, expired, expires_at, confirmation_token,
>   password_requested_at, roles , credentials_expired,
>   credentials_expire_at, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["admin", "admin", "helmis@gmail.de",
>   "helmis@gmail.de", 1, "msnp3rel3m880oggggkccg8wkwk4ks c",
>   "6s1k9SkufVf0AO0h+L4JKUtuKkaASIiQLMpuiD4qdZsX2WR9xm53DXVN6YnAuv8ui6PPSa
>   B0FwPpBwDzvI53GA==", null, 0, 0, null, null, null, "a:0:{}", 0, null,
>   2]: ORA-00903: invalid table name
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\OCI8Exception] ORA-00903: invalid table
>   name

Comment: `USER` is a reserved word, you can't call your table that (unless you quote the identifier everywhere). Did you choose that name or was it pre-configured?

Comment: it's preconfigured, il will ask change the name, thanks @AlexPoole.
Coud you Answer my question (not comment to set Resolved ? )
Thanks again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert query in Oracle: Invalid table name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387667/insert-query-in-oracle-invalid-table-name)